# How to emit a signal when cell/item is edited?

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtablewidget

I have a method that imports a table from a DB into a QTableWidget, and I want to edit a cell in the DB through the QTableWidget (when editing a cell by double-clicking it). I have tried to use the QTableWidget::cellChanged() signal, but the problem is that the signal is emitted for every cell in the table when importing from the DB. How can I emit a signal, only when the cell is changed "manually" after editing the text?

Comment: Why don't you use a QTableView coupled with a QSqlTableModel ?

Comment: disconnect signal while loading, reconnect after load?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Kamil said, disconnect signal while loading, reconnect after:
In Python that looks like:

```
self.disconnect(self.tableWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("cellChanged(int, int)"), self.DoSomething)
....import data....
self.connect(self.tableWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("cellChanged(int, int)"), self.DoSomething)
```

not sure, but I guess this is how it looks like for C++:

```
this->disconnect(this->tableWidget,QtCore::SIGNAL(cellChanged(int, int)),this->DoSomething)
```

I hope this helps too [link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Understanding_Signals_and_Slot_in_Qt)